# Android DatePicker/Dialog displaying incorrect month/s using min/max date

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm using the DatePickerDialog and the DatePicker to set a specific range.

```
datePicker.setMinDate(minDate);
datePicker.setMaxDate(maxDate);
```

If my min/max - dates are in the range of one month (eg.: 7.2.2014 - 27.2.2014), i still get the neighbour months displayed in the dialog (Jan, Mar).
If i choose the last month (Jan), the dialog automatically swaps to the minDate and the month switches back to Feb. Same thing for the future month.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this, so that i only get the months displayed, which are in my range?

Comment: i think Month starts with zero= January and 11 = december.. it may help you

Comment: Think u have misunderstood my topic. I have the choice of selecting march and january. But i only have a range between Febuary. So i dont want to let the other months(jan and mar) be displayed

Comment: @Maxi Hello, did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Month start from zero.....

So u have to use zero for january and 11 for December

Answer (score 0):

i have the same bug (and many peoples on StackOverflow)

my solution:

```
    monthPickerFrom =(DatePicker)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.monthPickerFrom);
    HideDay(monthPickerFrom);
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2007);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    monthPickerFrom.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    monthPickerFrom.setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    monthPickerFrom.init(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            ...
    });
```