# UWP CalendarDatePicker showing 'March' when minDate is set to 11th Feb

Tags: uwp, datepicker, uwp-xaml

UWP calendardatepicker is showing next month when the selected date is current date which has passed half of the days of month in the current view

As it can be referred from the pasted image screenshot that selected min date is 11th Feb but calendar is showing March in the month picker header[image]

Comment: I did not quite understand your question. Please provide the steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It is showing neighboring months when minDate is set (which is half the month passed in this case). So if I set the mindate as 9th Feb -> this works fine with the header showing February but if if minDate crosses half the month ie number of days of the current month < than the next month, it shows next month's name in the header. For eg: Here It should be February 2019, but instead it shows March, since March ( which is next/neighboring month ) has more days in the view than February.

Comment: You could submit an issue on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues

Answer (score 0):

Check your calendar once, date is correct i.e 11 Feb 2019.

Comment: U did mistake, this is not a question. Sorry

Comment: Can you see March,2019 just above picker? It should be February 2019.

Comment: Because, u open march calendar also, try to check in your system and scroll slowly, you may understand.. :)

Comment: Yeah so why is it happening is my question! When my date and pointer is on February calendar view why it is showing March.

Comment: Ok, check with MinDate as 9 Feb

Comment: Yeah I know for that it will work fine. Is this because of number of days in the current month are lesser than the next month?

Comment: Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779855/android-datepicker-dialog-displaying-incorrect-month-s-using-min-max-date

Answer (score 0):

You probably know already of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/1061). I'm working around at the moment by setting `minDate` to a January 1st and `maxDate` to a December 31st.

I haven't looked into also using `OutOfScope\BlackOut` day items (so set min and max dates to the above and blocking the dates I need to block through other means) but that's my next investigation step.